# Create array which stores odds from -6 to 38 in java

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I found an exercise which I can't solve, in the Arrays chapter.

The exercise says:

> Write code that creates an array named `odds` and stores all odd numbers between -6 and 38 into it using a `for` loop. Make the array's size exactly large enough to store the numbers.

The only solution I could come up with is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class exerciseOddsArray {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        oddsArray();
    }
    public static void oddsArray(){
        int odds = 0;
        for (int i = -6; i <= 38; i++){
            if (i % 2 == 1){
                odds++;
            }
        }
        int[] numbers = new int[odds];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i ++){
                for (int j = -6; j <= 38; j++){
                    if(j % 2 == 1){
                        numbers[i] = j;
                    }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

However, the program prints:

```
[37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37]
```

And I don't understand why.

Comment: You increment odds and you should be storing the odd number when found.

Comment: `int[] odds = IntStream.rangeClosed(-6, 38).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).toArray();`

Comment: You're running the same code for each array index. Why are you surprised they're all the same? You need to learn how to [debug your own code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Since it is an archive do you have the book and question number that you are doing?  Could be useful to associate with the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need nested FOR loops here. Just create an integer variable i to track your position in the array and increment it when adding each new item. PS... the array should have been called "odds" based on the specs of the assignment. I suggest renaming that variable you were using to count the number of odds to something else (e.g. numberOfOdds)

```
int[] odds= new int[numberOfOdds];
int i = 0;

for (int j = -6; j <= 38; j++)
{
  if(j % 2 == 1)
  {
      odds[i++] = j;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for each `i` you go over all the odd number `j` could have and assign them to `numbers[i]`. Instead, you could (should!) use a single loop:

```
int min = -6;
int max = 38;
int numOdds = (max - min) / 2; // Ok because both min and max are even

int[] odds = new int[numOdds];
int firstOdd = min;
if (min % 2 == 0) {
    ++firstOdd;
}
int index = 0;
for (int i = firstOdd; i < max; i += 2) {
    odds[index++] = i;
}
```

BTW - I get this is a school exercise, and that you're supposed to use a `for` loop, but frankly, Java 8's streams would solve this in a much neater fashion:

```
odds = IntStream.range(-6, 38).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

odds is a single value, you need to keep all the odd numbers you find in a list.

int odds = 0;

Answer (score 0):

U created `int` value and changed it 22 times i guess in first `for` loop. Then u add for your array the same value for another million times. Try to add your value to an array in first loop:

```
int[] odds= new int[numberOfOdds];
int i = 0;

for (int j = -6; j <= 38; j++)
{
  if(j % 2 == 1)
  {
      odds[i++] = j;
   }
}
```

Better use list if u don't know length of your set.

Answer (score 0):

You have two for loops when you only need one.
Unrolling the loops, your program is doing the following:

```
numbers[0] = -6; 
numbers[0] = -4;
numbers[0] = -2;
etc...
numbers[0] = 37;
numbers[1] = -6;
numbers[1] = -4;
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below below please

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getOddList(int min,int max){
       ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
       for( int i = min ; i <= max ; i++){
           if(i % 2 != 0){
               myList.add(i);
           }
       }
       return myList;
   }

[-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37]
```

I am assuming here min and max u r providing are in order. Also I have not tested my function. But this is an utility u can take. Please let me know

Comment: i can't use ArrayList. The exercise is asking specifically to use Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without knowing the number of odd numbers in advance.

```
int[] oddNumbers = IntStream.range(-6, 38)
            .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers. I changed my method to :

```
public static void oddsArray(){
        int numberOfOdds = 0;
        for (int i = -6; i <= 38; i++){
            if (i % 2 == 1){
                numberOfOdds++;
            }
        }
        int[] odds = new int[numberOfOdds];
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = -6; j < 39; j++){
            if (j % 2 == 1){
                odds[i++] = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it prints only the positive odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's necessary, but you could recreate the array holding the odd numbers each time you come across a new odd number. The method below will work no matter what range you are working with. I know that you can just use an ArrayList, but the question seems to want an array.

```
public class exerciseOddsArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    private int[] odds;
    private int start = -6;
    private int end = 38;

    odds = findOdds(start, end);

    if (odds== null)
        System.out.println("There weren't any odds");
    else
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(odds));
}

public static int[] findOdds(int start, int end) {
    private int[] arrayOfOdds;
    private int[] tempArray;

    private int numberOfOdds = 0;

    if (start < end)
    {
        while (start != end)
        {
            if ((start % 2) == 1)
            {
                if (arrayOfOdds != null)
                {
                    tempArray = new int[arrayOfOdds.length + 1];

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfOdds.length; i++)
                        tempArray[i] = arrayOfOdds[i];

                    tempArray[arrayOfOdds.length] = start;
                    arrayOfOdds = tempArray;
                } else {
                    arrayOfOdds = new int[1];
                    arrayOfOdds[0] = start;
                }
            }

            start++;
        }
    }

    return arrayOfOdds;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answer, this works

```
int[] odds = new int[22];
for(int i = 0;i<odds.length;i++){
odds[i]=2*i-5;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer and the code

Answer (score -1):

Number of odds is 22, this can be changed, but you must also change the parameters (ie. -6 and 38)

```
int[] odds = new int [22];
    int i = 0;
    for (int temp = -6; temp <= 38; temp++)
        if (Math.abs(temp % 2) == 1)
         {
         odds[i++] = temp;
         }
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the accepted answer?